# Is there an equivalent locking pattern in C++ to Java's Stamped Locking (with Optimistic Read)

Tags: java, performance, c++11, concurrency, c++14

I often find myself with a common concurrency problem when dealing with data structures that I want to keep thread-safe.  I'll be reading from these structures more than 99% of the time, and writing to them the remaining 1%.  Obtaining a lock for reads is usually a relatively expensive operation, and since my structures are very rarely written to it seems like the cost of the lock is often wasted.  There have been various locking solutions to this problem for different languages, but one interesting one I've used recently is Java 8's stamped locks with reader/writer locking.

Here is one example of this type of locking in Java 8.  It maintains a global mapping between int ids and words.  The method will create a new id for any word it hasn't seen, or return the previously created id if one exists.

```
private static HashMap<String, Integer> stringToId;
private static StampedLock lock;
private static Logger log;

public static int getIdFor(String token) {

    // First attempt an optimistic read
    long optimisticReadStamp = lock.tryOptimisticRead();
    try {
        if (stringToId.containsKey(token)) {
            int resultId = stringToId.get(token);
            if (lock.validate(optimisticReadStamp)) {
                return resultId;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.debug("Optimistic read failed with Exception: " + ex);
    }


    // The optimistic read failed, try a read with a stamped read lock
    long readLockStamp = lock.readLock();
    try {
        if (stringToId.containsKey(token)) {
            return stringToId.get(token);
        }
    } finally {
        lock.unlockRead(readLockStamp);
    }

    // Looks like the id we want is not there, let's get a write lock and add it
    long writeLockStamp = lock.writeLock();
    try {
        if (stringToId.containsKey(token)) {
            return stringToId.get(token);
        }
        int id = stringToId.size();
        stringToId.put(token, id);
        return id;
    } finally {
        lock.unlockWrite(writeLockStamp);
    }
}
```

This method will return the id in the first code block the vast majority of the time it's called, meaning it very rarely obtains a lock of any kind.  If the optimistic read call fails it falls back to a read/write lock.

There's another more simplistic example on Java's documentation page (which I'll link but not copy) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/StampedLock.html

My question is, is there any way to do something similar in modern C++?  Would it be possible to provide a unique stamp somewhere in memory every time a write lock is obtained on a thread-safe data structure? Would it then be possible to ensure that readers can check this data structure for modifications without requiring the readers to acquire a lock (either for the stamp or for the thread-safe data structure).  Would this have to be an operating system kernel feature, or could you do something like this with the current C++ memory model and primitives?

Comment: Hint: proper indenting would help with reading your source code. Plus: id() is a pretty bad name for a method. If you call the thing "getIdFor()" ... one has at least some chance of understanding what is about. Finally: maybe you want to read about the "single layer of abstraction" principle. You are doing **way too many** things in your one method.

Comment: I really hope that you have done measurement with existing methods in C++ like `shared_lock` and have found them not performant for your case. Otherwise, just jumping into new catchy stuff is bad though definitely interesting for research purposes.

Comment: I'm not a Java expert, but I'm pretty sure your Java example is broken. `stringToId.containsKey` call already exhibits undefined behavior if another thread happens to write to the map at the same time (which `tryOptimisticRead` doesn't prevent).

Comment: Igor: you're correct, added some error handling for the undefined behaviour.

Comment: Arunmu: we measured closely on the Java library and found that there was contention on machines with 36 cores, but indeed none on 4 core machines.  On the C++ side I haven't dug in in depth but some have made some initial measurements that indicate contention is a problem: https://github.com/moses-smt/mosesdecoder/issues/39 .  Mostly I am curious how you would implement such a feature on a theoretical level in a low-level language.

Comment: @Kellen Looks interesting. Perhaps you should also post it at comp.lang.c++

Comment: What kind of map supports `stringToId.containsKey(token)` in a different thread while someone is modifying it without internal locks?  It would be ... tricky.